# Cannot convert string to int in PHP

Tags: php

I'm having a tough time converting a value I read from socket connection into an integer. It's value tells me how many bytes are going to be received next.

```
$ar = fread($client, 4);
$binaryInt = unpack('N', $ar);
debug_to_console($binaryInt); //displays 16 (as expected)
$bred = fread($client, intval($binaryInt)); //intval returns 1
```

For some reason intval always evaluates to 1 and I can't figure out why. Btw the $ar variable is sent an integer from a java server I have running via this code sample

```
dOut.writeInt(data.length);
```

Thanks

**edit**

I finally got it. user2587326 below helped but instead of using intval(binaryInt[1]) it was just binaryInt[1].

Comment: We don't know what value you're looking at.

Comment: [unpack](http://php.net/manual/en/function.unpack.php) returns an array. Calling [intval](http://php.net/manual/en/function.intval.php) on an array will always return 1 and emit a notice, so what you are seeing is perfectly normal. What are you trying to do actually?

Comment: This value tells me how many bits I'll be receiving after the 4 byte integer value I'm trying to evaluate. "$bred = fread($client, ...)" is where it's not evaluating to what I want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are reading a 4-byte integer sent from your Java program over DataOutputStream to your PHP program over socket.

First, the fread($client, 4) call reads those 4 bytes as a string, 
then you convert them to an array with unpack(), taking 4-bytes at a time 
(format specifier 'N') thus resulting with an array with one element, so you just use:

<strike>intval(</strike>$binaryInt[1]<strike>)</strike> instead of intval($binaryInt) to obtain that number.

edit: but it works with intval too, it won't hurt it.

Comment: I got it, instead of using intval($binaryInt[1]) it's just $binaryInt[1]. $binaryInt[0] is the string value of the int in case anybody was wondering. http://php.net/manual/en/function.unpack.php under example #1 it is explained

Comment: You are correct, the intval() is not needed there. but $binaryInt[0] will not be available. You were confused by the example, which uses a different format specifier. In that case the array indexes are chars and int, not 0, and 1. The following example:
    <?php
    $x="1234";
    $b=unpack('N', $x);
    foreach ($b as $key => $value)
         print "\$b[$key] = $value\n";
    print gettype($b[1]) . "\n";
    print $b[1] . "\n";
    print $b[0];
    ?>

prints the following output:

    $b[1] = 825373492
    integer
    825373492
    PHP Notice:  Undefined offset: 0 in a.php on line 8